# Pretty Filter URL

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, query-variable

I'm developing an calender. It works very well for. My last point on the list is "make the url pretty".

Currently I have a **page** (example.com/my-calendar/) with a custom **php-template** which renders the calender sheet. It is displayed only one month per page. By a `$_GET` parameter I'm displaying the right sheet.

That means the URL `example.com/my-calendar/?base_date=05-2017` displayes me the calendar sheet for **may 2017**. But I wanted to have the URL like:

`example.com/my-calendar/05-2017`

or

`example.com/my-calendar/may-2017`

I'm playing around with [this tutorial](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/building-customized-urls-wordpress/) but did'nt get it work.

Comment: Why not https://example.com/my-calendar/2017-05 ?

Comment: The tutorial you linked has everything you'd need to accomplish what you're doing. Which part 'didn't work'?

Comment: @iguanarama I added a new comment with my current code :)

Comment: @prosti the value is not my problem. I want to know how to pass a parameter by rewrite rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my current code:

```
function hm_base_date_query_vars($vars) {
    $vars[] = 'base_date';

    return $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'hm_base_date_query_vars');

function hm_base_date_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^my-calendar/([^/]*)/?',
        'index.php?pagename=my-calendar&base_date=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action('init', 'hm_base_date_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);

$base_date_test = get_query_var('base_date');
```

on the url `example.com/my-calendar/foo` my var `$base_date_test` returns `null`

Maybe someone can help me. Thanks.

**// Edit:** It works. I tried to call the var in functions.php but I had to call it in my custom php template -.-